# Скрыть строку в ListView

Tags: getview, android, java

Всем привет! Подскажите как можно скрыть определённую строку в listview. Но скрыть надо не тогда когда идёт заполнение адаптером, а в любое другое время. Например по нажатию на определённую кнопку строка скрывалась. И скрывалась так чтобы она изчезла, а не так чтобы строка была, но она пустая.

Comment: Как я понимаю под скрыть строку подразумевается убрать item из ListView,но при этом оставить его в коллекции?

Comment: можно попробовать выставить нулевую высоту элементу.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте кастомный адаптер, который возвращает элемент нулевой высоты в `getView()`

Comment: хорошо попробую

Comment: а если view.setVisible(View.GONE); ?

Comment: @Gorets И как ты эту вьюху поймаешь то? `getView()` вызывается не тобой...

Comment: "@Gorets И как ты эту вьюху поймаешь то? getView() вызывается не тобой..." Полностью с вами согласен, поэтому стал делать по-другому.

Answer (score 0):

Короче я решил проблему немного другим способом.
Я просто из своего ArrayList удалил N строку и потом у адаптера вызвал метод notifyDataSetChanged() и всё стало нормально)

Comment: Ну, это неинтересно, это называется не скрыть строку, а удалить строку из коллекции. Тебе же уже спрашивали:

>Как я понимаю под скрыть строку подразумевается убрать item из >ListView,но при этом оставить его в коллекции?

Comment: :-))))) Понимаю что не интересно))

Comment: @RomkaKraynov, в макете для адаптера создаёшь `layout` и даёшь`layout.id`. В адаптере по нажатию на кнопку, этот layout  скрываешь, `layout.setVisibility.(View.GONE)`, позицию находишь по позиции нажатой кнопки. Это чтоб строчку списка скрыть

Answer (score 0):

В макете для адаптера создаёшь `layout` и даёшь`layout.id`. Туда размещаешь все элементы шаблона. В адаптере по нажатию на кнопку, этот layout скрываешь, `layout.setVisibility.(View.GONE)`, позицию находишь по позиции нажатой кнопки. Это чтоб строчку списка скрыть